# HTML align text with button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to horizontally align some code and a button.
For that, I am using the following code:

```
<div className="panel-heading">
      <h2 className="panel-title headingText">Attributes</h2>   
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-info btn-sml pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newListModal">New List</button>
</div>
```

However, the two are not aligned(the button is the blue thing at the bottom, I would like it to be more central, just like the text):

[image]

How could I align the text and button horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply Css to fulfill your requirement like this

```
.panel-heading, .headingText
    {
        display:inline-block;
        padding:10px;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div classname="panel-heading">
    <h4 classname="panel-title headingText" style="float:left">Attributes</h4>
    <button type="button" style="float:left;padding:10px" classname="btn btn-info btn-sml pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newListModal">New List</button>
</div>
```

This should Work. You can remove padding property